# Custom edge style (e.g. brush stroke, writing ink, etc.)

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, visualization, generative-art

I would like to draw a graph with *Mathematica* in such a way that it looks like a handmade drawing or painting. To be more precise, is there a way to set a custom edge style such that it looks made with writing ink or with a brush stroke?

If this is not possible in *Mathematica*, are you aware of any software that can be used to obtain such an effect? If so, what is the best format in which to export my graph?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xkcd-style graphs](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs)

Comment: The XKCD question is *one* possible answer, but what if I want strokes like [these](http://artisticpov.jessemaccabe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/brushStrokes_002.jpg)?  Maybe too early for marking as duplicate?

Comment: @Karsten 7, thanks for the link, but it is not exactly what I was looking for. Besides, does the xkcd-style function work with the Mathematica graph objects (nodes and edges)?

Comment: By graph, do you mean plot or network?  @J.M. I thought he meant plot, as in `Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10}]`.

Comment: I mean a network

Comment: `xkcdConvert` seems to work with graphs, though it takes an atrociously long time and it's hard to say if that's the kind of result desired.

Comment: @Szabolcs, the comment above yours mentioned nodes and edges, so I retagged.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13376); the proposal there ought to be adaptable to drawing fancy edges.

Comment: So then you only want to draw straight line edges, no curves?  Nothing like `DirectedGraph[RandomGraph[{10, 20}], "Acyclic"]`?  We could take a bitmap of a brush stroke and rescale (lengthen) it to fit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You ought to use `EdgeRenderingFunction` to achieve this.

First, import a graphic for a brushstroke:

```
BRUSH = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "brush.png"]
```

Then use the `EdgeRenderingFunction` option in `GraphPlot` to obtain the image.

```
GraphPlot[Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}],
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Inset[BRUSH, Mean[#1], Automatic, 1.7, #[[2]] - #[[1]]]} &),
 VertexRenderingFunction -> None
]
```

The value `1.7` was something I tweaked based on my image. I recommend using a well-cropped image with a transparent background.

I used the image:

[image: brush-stroke]

to obtain the following graph:

[image: triangle]

You can make this more complex by trying to use multiple different images as brushstrokes, manually specifying your vertex coordinates, etc.

Comment: PS Use only directed edges in your graphs, unless you want a double-brush-stroke in each direction.

Comment: You can use `EdgeShapeFunction` for `Graph`.

Comment: That's odd, when I tried to find the corresponding option for `Graph`, I didn't see it, but indeed, Szabolcs is correct. That option for `Graph` works just as well (seems to be equivalent or nearly equivalent) and bypasses `GraphPlot`.

Answer (score 10):

Use [Kellen Myers's method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97558/17) but with randomly generated brush-style strokes:

```
Clear[baseStroke]
baseStroke :=
    Graphics[{
               Black,
               FilledCurve@
                   BSplineCurve[{{2,0},{1,0},{0,-0.2},{-0.1,0},{0,0.2},{1,.1}},
                                SplineClosed -> True]
             }, PlotRange -> {{-.3, 2}, {-.5, .5}}] // 
                        ExportString[#, "PDF"] & // ImportString[#, "PDF"][[1]] & // 
                Inactive[Graphics] @@ # & //
            Module[{fc = Cases[#, _FilledCurve, ∞][[1]], 
                        pr = Cases[#, (PlotRange -> range_) :> range, ∞][[1]],
                            destpr, pts, shapeshifter, 
                        shapeshiftFactor = RandomReal[{1, 2}] {.1, .09}},
                    destpr = 
                        MapAt[# - Mean[#] &, 
                            MapAt[#/Max@# &, pr, 2], 2];
                    pts = fc[[2, 1]];
                    pts = 
                        MapThread[Rescale, {pts, pr, destpr}];
                    shapeshifter = 
                        1 + shapeshiftFactor # & /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {Length@pts, 2}];
                    pts = shapeshifter pts;
                    # /. {
                            _FilledCurve :> ReplacePart[fc, {{2, 1}} -> pts],
                            (PlotRange -> _) :> (PlotRange -> destpr)
                            }
                    ] & // Activate

GraphPlot[Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}], 
    EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Inset[baseStroke, Mean[#1], Automatic, 
                        1.7, #[[2]] - #[[1]]]} &), VertexRenderingFunction -> None]
```

[image: GraphPlot with simulated brush stroke]

## Reference:

- [A Computational Approach to Digital Chinese Painting and Calligraphy](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-88148-3)
- [Non-Photorealistic Computer Graphics: Modeling, Rendering, and Animation](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/non-photorealistic-computer-graphics-thomas-strothotte/1111340539?ean=9781558607873)

Comment: My browser cannot display that `` character :-(

Comment: @Szabolcs They are mma's \[Tr]character :)

Answer (score 4):

Just like in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11393), perturbation with one-dimensional Perlin noise can be used to draw fuzzy-looking lines. Here is one way of going about it:

```
fBm = With[{permutations =
            Apply[Join, ConstantArray[RandomSample[Range[0, 255]], 2]]}, 
           Compile[{{x, _Real}}, 
                   Module[{xf = Floor[x], xi, xa, u, i, j},
                          xi = Mod[xf, 32] + 1; xa = x - xf;
                          u = xa*xa*xa*(10. + xa*(xa*6. - 15.));
                          i = permutations[[permutations[[xi]] + 1]];
                          j = permutations[[permutations[[xi + 1]] + 1]];
                          (2 Boole[OddQ[i]] - 1)*xa*(1. - u) +
                          (2 Boole[OddQ[j]] - 1)*(xa - 1.)*u], 
                   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]];

handdrawn[p1_, p2_, fr_, sh_, divisor_, n_] := With[{cs = Normalize[p2 - p1]}, 
          BSplineCurve[Table[(1 - t) p1 + t p2 +
                             {0, fBm[fr (10 t + sh)]/ divisor}.{cs, Cross[cs]},
                             {t, 0, 1, 1/n}]]]
```

The `handdrawn[]` edge function can then be used like so:

```
PetersenGraph[5, 2, 
              EdgeShapeFunction -> Function[{pts, e},
                                            handdrawn[pts[[1]], pts[[2]],
                                                      20, 1/10, 30, 51]],
              EdgeStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], ColorData[61, 8]], 
              VertexStyle -> ColorData[61, 8]]
```

[image: fuzzy Petersen graph]

The only caveat of `handdrawn[]` is that tweaking the last four parameters is usually needed to arrive at a satisfactory-looking fuzzy line.

Comment: Is every edge here the same shape (stretched to fit the length between each pair of vertices accordingly)? Or is each one randomized in its own way? I'm trying to discern visually whether this ends up giving you copies of the same random edge shape or different random perturbations on each edge.

Comment: In the version presented here, yes. Additional randomization could be provided by something like `EdgeShapeFunction -> Function[{pts, e}, handdrawn[pts[[1]], pts[[2]], RandomReal[{20, 30}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}/5], 30, 51]]`.

Comment: Doesn't changing `Set` to `SetDelay` for `fBm` make all lines shaped individually?

Comment: @Karsten, yes, that's another possible way to make it look more random.