# How to discretize a BezierCurve?

Tags: graphics, bugs, regions, splines

**Bug introduced in version 10.0 and fixed in version 12.0**

 `DiscretizeGraphics` is new in 10.0.

---

I need to create a discretized region from a `BezierCurve`.

This is one of my curves:

```
pt = {{93.2759`, 277.0452`}, {90.6249`, 
      273.3252`}, {79.7499`, 255.70020000000002`}, {76.9999`, 
      250.70020000000002`}, {74.2499`, 
      245.70020000000002`}, {70.2499`, 
      237.70020000000002`}, {69.9999`, 235.32520000000002`}};
g = Graphics[{BezierCurve[pt]}];
```

`DiscretizeGraphics` creates points which are close to the curve, but clearly not on it.

Please try

```
Show[g, DiscretizeGraphics[g]]
```

This is a magnified portion of the result:

[image]

There is a small but consistent difference between the discretized version and the original graphics.

What is going on?

Which one is wrong?  The `BezierCurve` rendering or the discretization?  If it's the discretization, then:

What workarounds are there for the problem?  Could I sample the points on the curve using `BezierFunction`?  If yes, how exactly?  `BezierFunction[points]` and `BezierCurve[points]` don't seem to represent the same curve.

---

My ultimate aim is to discretize some objects imported from a PDF.  One of them is a closed `JoinedCurve` (or `FilledCurve`) and I need to use it to filter certain points which are inside the region.  The other one (shown above) is a non-closed `JoinedCurve`, consisting of `BezierCurve[..., SplineDegree -> 3]` and `Line[...]` segments.  `DiscretizeGraphics` does not work on `JoinedCurve`/`FilledCurve`.

---

Additional information:

`BezierFunction` and `BezierCurve` do not give the same result in the following test:

```
ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[pt][x], {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> {BezierCurve[pt]}]
```

Again there is a small but consistent difference.  Why?

Here's a different point set where `BezierCurve` and `BezierFunction` give very different results.  How can I use `BezierFunction` to reproduce the same thing I see with `BezierCurve`?

```
pt = {{85.6699, 270.639}, {81.4849, 265.53}, {72.1939, 247.082}, {69.5059, 
  244.27}, {66.8189, 241.46}, {65.3979, 237.927}, {64.1759, 
  236.649}, {62.9539, 235.372}, {75.0969, 229.142}, {76.6069, 
  228.676}, {78.1179, 228.21}, {75.1319, 234.644}, {75.2469, 
  237.147}, {75.3609, 239.65}, {80.5859, 252.02}, {82.9949, 
  256.076}, {85.4049, 260.131}, {92.1679, 270.779}, {93.5919, 
  274.19}, {95.0159, 277.6}, {92.9719, 279.555}, {85.6699, 270.639}}
```

---

[Posted a related question on Wolfram Community.](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/601632?p_p_auth=7TgRaUyu)

Comment: You can export a bspline as pdf then import the pdf. See my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97669/17).

Comment: The other possibility is to use `ParametricPlot[]` + `BezierFunction[]` to create a `Line[]` primitive that should now be easily discretized. Can you give an example where `BezierCurve[]` doesn't seem to give the same result as my proposal?

Comment: With respect to `JoinedCurve[]`/`FilledCurve[]`: if memory serves Simon Woods has a post somewhere on how to split those into components.

Comment: @J.M. The same example from this post doesn't.  `ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[pt][x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {BezierCurve[pt]}]`, where `pt` are the points from above.

Comment: @Silvia If I export/import to/from PDF, I still get a `JoinedCurve` with a `BezierCurve` inside (after decoding using ``GeometricFunctions`DecodeJoinedCurve``), so I'm back to the same problem.  There's also an additional problem: the coordinates have all changed.  I need to do measurements on these objects (imported form a single PDF), so they must all be in the same coordinate system.

Comment: @J.M. With these different set of points, `{{85.6699, 270.639}, {81.4849, 265.53}, {72.1939, 247.082}, {69.5059, 
  244.27}, {66.8189, 241.46}, {65.3979, 237.927}, {64.1759, 
  236.649}, {62.9539, 235.372}, {75.0969, 229.142}, {76.6069, 
  228.676}, {78.1179, 228.21}, {75.1319, 234.644}, {75.2469, 
  237.147}, {75.3609, 239.65}, {80.5859, 252.02}, {82.9949, 
  256.076}, {85.4049, 260.131}, {92.1679, 270.779}, {93.5919, 
  274.19}, {95.0159, 277.6}, {92.9719, 279.555}, {85.6699, 270.639}}`, the above ParametricPlot also gives differing results.  Is it because I need to set `SplineDegrees`?

Comment: `bfun = BezierFunction[pt]; ParametricPlot[bfun[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 25, Prolog -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], ColorData[97, 2]], BezierCurve[pt]}]` gives [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vr6JP.png) for me.

Comment: It's one possibility, yes: you may want to ensure that the two curves do have the same degree, though honestly I can't think of a situation that doesn't produce cubic curves.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I get the same.  There is a small but persistent difference.  I don't understand why and I worry it's going to turn into a big difference for some other input data.  Sorry for having only this almost straight curv as an example ...

Comment: Something doesn't seem right with `BezierFunction[]`; it seems it's not allowing an explicit `SplineDegree` setting. I don't remember this being the case in version 8...

Comment: @J.M. The only `SplineDegree` setting it accepts from me is `Length[pt] - 1`.

Comment: Maybe we should try roping in somebody with an earlier version to check. I'm positive that discrepancy wasn't there before.

Comment: @Jacob, can you test Szabolcs's observations, please?

Comment: @Jacob, I was talking about comparing the result of `BezierCurve[]` and `BezierFunction[]` + `ParametricPlot[]`, actually. As I mentioned, I don't believe there was a discrepancy like this in version 8, and was hoping for a confirmatory test.

Comment: I do see the same in v9.  I don't have v8 handy.

Comment: I also see the [same in version 8](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tIMYf.png).

Comment: For the last example, things look pretty much identical in v8 and v10

Comment: That's funny... @Jacob, does it still happen after you increase the `PlotPoints` setting?

Comment: @J.M. yeah, the picture hardly changes with `PlotPoints-> 10000`

Comment: Could you tell me how to use the *undocumented* functions in the context ``GeometricFunctions```? I discovered that there are my useful functions. BTW, is it possible to see the **internal code** of these function by some method, like `PrintDifitions[]` that in package **GeneralUtilities**? Thanks.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG I only know this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/570/12

Comment: I think this has been fixed in 12.0.

Comment: I tested this on Windows and the bug seems to be fixed in 12.0. If others find otherwise status please feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 12):

This was solved with help from Shutao Tang, J.M., Sander Huisman and Eric Rimbey.

1. Why do `BezierFunction[pt]` and `BezierCurve[pt]` not agree?

   Because `BezierCurve` uses `SplineDegree -> 3` by default and `BezierFunction` always uses degree `Length[pt] - 1` (not settable).
2. Why does `DiscretizeGraphics` give a bad result?

   Because it appears to use (the equivalent of) `BezierFunction[pt]` internally.  This is a bug.  Witness:

   ```
   pt = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}};
   g = Graphics[{BezierCurve[pt]}];
   Show[g, 
     ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[pt][x], {x, 0, 1}, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Yellow]], 
    DiscretizeGraphics[g]
   ]
   ```

   [image: Mathematica graphics]
3. How can we reproduce a `BezierCurve` using `BezierFunction`?

   By stitching together several degree-3 (or less) `BezierFunction`s:

   ```
   funs = BezierFunction /@ Partition[pt, 4, 3, {1, 1}, {}];
   Show[Table[ParametricPlot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}], {f, funs}], PlotRange -> All]
   ```

   [image: Mathematica graphics]

   `DiscretizeGraphics` can then be applied to this.

Comment: do you get an error when you enter the line `funs = BezierFunction /@ Partition[pt, 4, 3, {1, 1}, {}];`?  I find that the `Partition` command creates a list whose last element only has one point.  I can only get it to work without error if I add `[[;;-2]]` after the `Partition`