# Why is DiscretizeGraphics missing points on my curve?

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, regions, splines, discretization

I have a graphics expression which renders nicely as a closed curve when put in `Graphics`, I don't understand why I can't get the lines from DiscretizeGraphics or BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics:

```
 p = {BSplineCurve[{{0.1288208346384372`, 
         0.24716061799090383`}, {0.18307091717113483`, 
         0.29633799186027077`}, {0.18104183370580254`, 
         0.25496700929944494`}, {0.22444189973196066`, 
         0.2943089083949385`}, {0.18307091717113483`, 
         0.29633799186027077`}, {0.23732099970383244`, 
         0.34551536572963765`}}, SplineWeights -> {1, 15, 25, 25, 15, 1}],
       BSplineCurve[{{0.1288208346384372`, 
         0.47866942629949966`}, {0.18307091717113483`, 
         0.41209239601456865`}, {0.13474007204408336`, 
         0.417023175115462`}, {0.17814013807024148`, 
         0.3637615508875172`}, {0.18307091717113483`, 
         0.41209239601456865`}, {0.23732099970383244`, 
         0.34551536572963765`}}, SplineWeights -> {1, 15, 25, 25, 15, 1}],
       Line[{{0.1288208346384372`, 
         0.24716061799090383`}, {0.1288208346384372`, 
         0.47866942629949966`}}]}
{Graphics@p, DiscretizeGraphics[p]}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

I looked though the options but couldn't find any `PlotPoints` like option.

Comment: `PlotRange` doesn't seem to be the issue. However, for reasons that I don't fully understand, removing the `SplineWeights` in your `BSplineCurve`s improves the situation, but doesn't solve it completely.

Comment: @MarcoB yes is see that, better but still has wholes... weird!

Comment: Annoyingly, `JoinedCurve[]` does not play well with `DiscretizeGraphics[]`.

Comment: I don't now the exact answer but my guess is the problem is with line and BSplineCurve combination. The line is bounded piece wise linear primitive and BSplineCurve is a nonlinear primitive with an only approximation represented. If you try BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics you get an error saying _'BoundaryMeshRegion::buncl: At least one boundary was not closed in'_. So the line and spline joined points does not overlap due to approximation of spline.

Comment: @s.s.o how can I fix that

Comment: Hi, you have asked once a question about indenting sub cells like text to last item etc. Can't find it now, could you point me to it?

Comment: `BezierCurve` won't discretize correctly (there's a bug).  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98147/12  I haven't read your question in detail, but I thought I should warn you about this in case `BSplineCurve` has problems too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So `DiscretizeGraphics` seems to always miss the first or last point of a `BSplineCurve` (it seems to do it with a `BezierCurve` as well).  Here's the simplest example of this,

```
pts = {{.5, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {.5, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {.5, 0}};
GraphicsRow[{Graphics@#, DiscretizeGraphics@#} &@BSplineCurve[pts], 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Why does it do this?  Not sure, hopefully one of the kernel developers that hang around here can chime in.  It seems at first to be related to [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98162/9490) with discretizing Bezier curves, but there you have the problem that `BezierFunction` is awful.  Here we have a workaround, because `BSplineFunction` works just fine.

Just extract the points from the curve, create a `Line` object from them, and discretize that.  Inspiration came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28860072/4712538) over on stackoverflow,

```
discretizableBSplineCurve[pts_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Line@(BSplineFunction[pts, 
     Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[BSplineCurve]]]] /@ 
    Range[0, 1, .01])
```

Trying it on the above case,

```
GraphicsRow[{Graphics@#, DiscretizeGraphics@#} &@
  discretizableBSplineCurve[pts], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Here it is applied to puzzle piece M.R. is drawing,

```
p1 = {discretizableBSplineCurve[{{0.1288208346384372`, 
      0.24716061799090383`}, {0.18307091717113483`, 
      0.29633799186027077`}, {0.18104183370580254`, 
      0.25496700929944494`}, {0.22444189973196066`, 
      0.2943089083949385`}, {0.18307091717113483`, 
      0.29633799186027077`}, {0.23732099970383244`, 
      0.34551536572963765`}}, 
    SplineWeights -> {1, 15, 25, 25, 15, 1}], 
   discretizableBSplineCurve[{{0.1288208346384372`, 
      0.47866942629949966`}, {0.18307091717113483`, 
      0.41209239601456865`}, {0.13474007204408336`, 
      0.417023175115462`}, {0.17814013807024148`, 
      0.3637615508875172`}, {0.18307091717113483`, 
      0.41209239601456865`}, {0.23732099970383244`, 
      0.34551536572963765`}}, 
    SplineWeights -> {1, 15, 25, 25, 15, 1}], 
   Line[{{0.1288208346384372`, 
      0.24716061799090383`}, {0.1288208346384372`, 
      0.47866942629949966`}}]};
{Graphics@p1, DiscretizeGraphics[p1]}
```

[image]

Another way to do it would be to modify 'DiscretGraphics`, that way you can work with objects that still have the head`BSplineCurve`.

```
discretizeGraphics2[graphics_] := 
 DiscretizeGraphics@(graphics /. {BSplineCurve[
       a__] :> (Line@(BSplineFunction[a] /@ Range[0, 1, .01]))});
```

Trying this on `p` as defined in the OP,

```
{DiscretizeGraphics@p, discretizeGraphics2@p}
```

[image]

**Edit** So I'm looking at that last picture and thinking that they don't look identical, and wondering if my strategy of converting to a line first messes up the graphic.  But when compared to the original, un-discretized version, my system produces a much more faithful reproduction when pre-converting the curve:

```
GraphicsRow[{Show[{Graphics@p, DiscretizeGraphics@p}], 
  Show[{Graphics@p, discretizeGraphics2@p}]}]
```

[image]

And I can't seem to improve the plot on the left with any combination of options to `DiscretizeGraphics` (`AccuracyGoal`, `PerformanceGoal`, `PrecisionGoal`, or `MeshQualityGoal`).  It must be possible, as M.R.'s DiscretizeGraphics in his example image looks much better than mine.  I'm using version 10.2, perhaps it has been improved in version 10.3?

**Edit2** Following J.M.'s suggestion, I've worked up a version that uses `ParametricPlot` to adaptively sample the `BSplineFunction`.  It seems to be an order of magnitude slower (not that it is all that slow), and ends up plotting many more points, but it could lead to a more faithful reproduction of the original `BSplineCurve` objects,

```
discretizeGraphics2b[graphics_] := 
 DiscretizeGraphics@(graphics /. {BSplineCurve[
       a__] :> (Line@(Cases[
          ParametricPlot[BSplineFunction[a][t], {t, 0, 1}], 
          Line[{x__}] :> x, \[Infinity]]))});

{discretizeGraphics2@p,
 discretizeGraphics2b@p}
```

[image]

Comment: For the first part you can use pts = {{.5, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {.5, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}; **Graphics@BSplineCurve[pts, SplineClosed -> True]** so that you don,'t need to duplicate the first or last point. There is a bug I thing in DiscretizeGraphics. It forgets to ckeck if the shape is closed. And algorithm skips the last segment.

Comment: ahhh, I don't know much about `BSplineCurve`, I grabbed that list of points from the help page.  But even for a non-closed `BSplineCurve`, `DiscretizeGraphics` will omit points.  Try this, `gr = Graphics[{BezierCurve[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {5, 2}}]}];
dgr = DiscretizeGraphics[gr];
Show[gr, dgr]`

Comment: Yes, I think here is a bug in DiscretizeGraphics  algorithm skips the last segment.

Comment: You might consider using `ParametricPlot[]` to adaptively sample your `BSplineFunction[]`.

Comment: @J.M. then how do I combine the graphics together?  If I just use `Show[g1,g2]` where `g1` and `g2` are two different `ParametricPlot`s, with different `PlotRange`s, it won't show the whole thing.  But if they are `Line` objects, `Graphics[g1,g2]` automatically shows everything.

Comment: Scratch that, if I apply `PlotRange->All` then I can combine them, but it does require and extra `Show`, meaning that I need to supply a `Graphics` to the `Line` object from `p` in order to combine them.  How would I evaluate whether this was better?

Comment: Well, after using `ParametricPlot[]`, you could extract the `Line[]` object representing the curve, after a preprocessing with `Normal[]` to get rid of `GraphicsComplex[]`.

Comment: It seems to work without `Normal`, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 7):

An alternate, i suspect faster, way to get your evenly spaced points,
using `linepoints` from here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39457/2079

```
DiscretizeGraphics@
 Line[linepoints[
    Table[ BSplineFunction[{{0.1288208346384372`, 
         0.24716061799090383`}, {0.18307091717113483`, 
         0.29633799186027077`}, {0.18104183370580254`, 
         0.25496700929944494`}, {0.22444189973196066`, 
         0.2943089083949385`}, {0.18307091717113483`, 
         0.29633799186027077`}, {0.23732099970383244`, 
         0.34551536572963765`}}, 
       SplineWeights -> {1, 15, 25, 25, 15, 1}][t] , {t, 0, 
      1, .001}] , 50]~Join~
   linepoints[
    Table[BSplineFunction[{{0.1288208346384372`, 
         0.47866942629949966`}, {0.18307091717113483`, 
         0.41209239601456865`}, {0.13474007204408336`, 
         0.417023175115462`}, {0.17814013807024148`, 
         0.3637615508875172`}, {0.18307091717113483`, 
         0.41209239601456865`}, {0.23732099970383244`, 
         0.34551536572963765`}}, 
       SplineWeights -> {1, 15, 25, 25, 15, 1}][t] , {t, 1, 
      0, -.001}], 50]~
   Join~{{0.1288208346384372`, 
     0.24716061799090383`}, {0.1288208346384372`, 
     0.47866942629949966`}}]
```

[image] [image]

(second version obtained applying `linepoints` to the straight edge line as well )