# Why is there a discrepancy between JoinedCurve/FilledCurve and the underlying BSplineCurve segments?

Tags: graphics, splines

This may be related to [How to discretize a BezierCurve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98147), but this question deals with `BSplineCurve`s with specific `SplineWeights`, so I don't think the answers there will help here.

---

**Background**

I am using version 11.3.0.0 (on Mac OS 10.11.5).

I recently wrote an `Arc` function that takes the same arguments as `Circle`. This spits out a list of degree 2 `BSplineCurve`s with the appropriate `SplineWeights` to generate pieces of a circle. I did this so that the last piece can be wrapped in an `Arrow` to make circular-arc arrows.

I also wanted to use `JoinedCurve` and `FilledCurve` with the arcs, which cannot be done with `Circle`.

**The Problem**

The code

```
segments = {
   BSplineCurve[{{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}],  
   BSplineCurve[{{0,1},{-1,1},{-1,0}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}]  
};
Graphics[{{Red,segments},JoinedCurve[segments]}]
```

produces the output

[image: joined curve bug]

The red curve is drawn first and seems to be correct. The black curve is drawn second and overlays the first segment properly; however, the second segment doesn't quite follow the red circle. Ideally, the black curve should completely obscure the red curve.

I was thinking that the problem might be that that `JoinedCurve` was trying to use a cubic spline to try to match the quadratic rational spline; however, then the first segment would not overlay so precisely (a cubic spline cannot exactly trace an arc of a circle unless it employs the proper weights).

The same problem is displayed by `FilledCurve`:

```
segments = {
   BSplineCurve[{{1/4,-3/4},{1,-3/4},{1,0}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}],
   BSplineCurve[{{1,0},{1,3/4},{1/4,3/4}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}],
   Line[{{1/4,3/4},{-1/4,3/4}}],
   BSplineCurve[{{-1/4,3/4},{-1,3/4},{-1,0}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}],
   BSplineCurve[{{-1,0},{-1,-3/4},{-1/4,-3/4}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}],
   Line[{{-1/4,-3/4},{1/4,-3/4}}]
};
Graphics[{{Red,segments},Lighter[Purple,3/4],FilledCurve[segments]}]
```

[image: filled curve bug]

Does anyone know what is going on here, and whether this persists in newer versions as well.

---

**The Masked Pumpkin**

This problem arose when I was creating my Gravatar for Halloween 2020:

[image]

Hopefully, I can remove the mask by next Halloween.

Answer (score 10):

**1. To get *"the black curve (to) completely obscure the red curve"***

You can replace `BSplineCurve`s with `Line`s using [`BSplineFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html):

```
sw = {1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1};
segments = {BSplineCurve[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, SplineWeights -> sw], 
  BSplineCurve[{{0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}}, SplineWeights -> sw]}; 

Graphics[{Red , segments, Black, Dashed, 
  JoinedCurve[segments /. 
    BSplineCurve[a__] :> Line[BSplineFunction[a] /@ Subdivide[100]]]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Similarly, for `FilledCurve`:

```
segments = {BSplineCurve[{{1/4, -(3/4)}, {1, -(3/4)}, {1, 0}}, 
    SplineWeights -> {1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}], 
   BSplineCurve[{{1, 0}, {1, 3/4}, {1/4, 3/4}}, 
    SplineWeights -> {1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}], 
   Line[{{1/4, 3/4}, {-(1/4), 3/4}}], 
   BSplineCurve[{{-(1/4), 3/4}, {-1, 3/4}, {-1, 0}}, 
    SplineWeights -> {1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}], 
   BSplineCurve[{{-1, 0}, {-1, -(3/4)}, {-(1/4), -(3/4)}}, 
    SplineWeights -> {1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}], 
   Line[{{-(1/4), -(3/4)}, {1/4, -(3/4)}}]};

Graphics[{Red, segments, EdgeForm[{Dashed, Black}], FaceForm[Opacity[.25, Blue]], 
  FilledCurve[segments /. 
    BSplineCurve[a__] :> Line[BSplineFunction[a] /@ Subdivide[100]]]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**2.  *"Why is there a discrepancy?"***

[`JoinedCurve >> Details and Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JoinedCurve.html):

[image]

and [`FilledCurve >> Details and options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve.html)

[image]

That is, `JoinedCurve` and `FilledCurve`  both prepend the coordinate list of segment `i+1` with the last coordinate of segment `i`. This does not create an issue when segment primitives are `Line`s; but with `BezierCurve` and `BSplineCurve` repeated coordinates give a different picture. (It is unfortunate that these functions seem not to check if the first coordinate of segment `i+1` is already the same as th last coordinate of segment `i` before inserting a new point).

What spline weight is assigned to the new point is anyone's guess. With a *small* weight, say `10^-5`, for the newly inserted point we can replicate the output from `JoinedCurve[segments]`:

```
segmentsb = {BSplineCurve[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, SplineWeights -> sw], 
   BSplineCurve[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}}, 
    SplineWeights -> Prepend[10^-5] @ sw]};

Graphics[{Green, segmentsb, Black, Dashed, 
  JoinedCurve[segments]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I saw the description in the documentation, which says "... is equivalent to ..." Obviously, they are not equivalent. I have written a function which takes the points that will be duplicated out of the data. This makes things work as I had expected.

Answer (score 8):

To avoid the issue mentioned by kglr where points are repeated, you can just add another layer of list:

```
segments = {
    BSplineCurve[{{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}],
    BSplineCurve[{{0,1},{-1,1},{-1,0}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}]
};
Graphics[{{Red,segments}, JoinedCurve[List/@segments]}]
```

[image]

**Update**

Now that the ["SplineCircle"](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/published/FunctionRepository/resources/SplineCircle) [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) works again, you could use it to create the [`BSplineCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineCurve) objects:

```
segments = {
    ResourceFunction["SplineCircle"][{1/4, 0}, 3/4, {1, 0}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}],
    Line[{{1/4, 3/4}, {-1/4, 3/4}}],
    ResourceFunction["SplineCircle"][{-1/4,0}, 3/4, {1, 0}, {Pi/2, 3Pi/2}],
    Line[{{-1/4, -3/4}, {1/4, -3/4}}]
};

Graphics[{{Red, segments}, Lighter[Purple, 3/4], FilledCurve[segments]}]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) This works for `JoinedCurve`, but gives odd output when applied to the `FilledCurve` example.

Comment: @robjohn You're right, my approach doesn't work for FilledCurve. Why don't you create a single BSplineCurve instead of trying to use JoinedCurve/FilledCurve to connect multiple BSplineCurves?

Comment: I thought about it, but it seemed easier to put together the pieces than to work out the placement all of the knots to get the same output. Furthermore, I still need to use FilledCurve to fill the inside, anyway.

Comment: @robjohn It's too bad the "SplineCircle" resource function is broken, otherwise you could just use that.

Comment: Does any one have a reference to understanding `SplineWeights`?  The documentation illustrates how to use them, but not their definition.

Is it obvious that the o.p.'s choice of  `SplineWeights -> {1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}` is the correct one? Why?

Comment: @Craig, at least for making NURBS circular arcs, [Piegl and Tiller](https://doi.org/10.1109/38.35537) explain where the weights come from.

Comment: Thanks. @J.M. $\phantom{}$

Answer (score 8):

**Additional Problem**

In addition to the two problems I mentioned above, there was a third problem that

```
segments = {
   BSplineCurve[{{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}],
   BSplineCurve[{{0,1},{-1,1},{-1,0}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}]
};
Graphics[{Arrow[JoinedCurve[segments]}]
```

produced no output.

The other answers do get to the root cause of the problem; that is, the addition of points to the segments by `JoinedCurve` and `FilledCurve`. However, approximating the curve with small line segments produces choppy output. Encapsulating the segments in `List`s produces odd results when filled.

---

**Solution to All Three Problems**

To solve all three problems and produce a nice, smooth curve, I ended up writing a function which removes the points that are going to be added by `JoinedCurve` and `FilledCurve`.  This function is

```
alef = {First[#],Sequence @@ MapAt[Rest,Rest[#],{All,1}]}&
```

In a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233846/why-is-there-a-discrepency-between-joinedcurve-filledcurve-and-the-underlying-bs/233868#comment591151_233868), [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) notes that the following is equivalent and shorter

```
alef = MapAt[Rest,#,{2;;,1}]&
```

The name is an acronym for "assume last equals first".

**1. JoinedCurve Problem**

```
segments = {
   BSplineCurve[{{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}],
   BSplineCurve[{{0,1},{-1,1},{-1,0}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}]
};
Graphics[{{Red,segments},JoinedCurve[alef[segments]]}]
```

produces

[image: joined curve bug]

as desired.

**2. Arrow and JoinedCurve Problem**

```
segments = {
   BSplineCurve[{{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}],
   BSplineCurve[{{0,1},{-1,1},{-1,0}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}]
};
Graphics[{Arrow[JoinedCurve[alef[segments]]]}]
```

produces

[image: arrow joined curve bug]

as desired.

**3. FilledCurve Problem**

```
segments = {
   BSplineCurve[{{1/4,-3/4},{1,-3/4},{1,0}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}],
   BSplineCurve[{{1,0},{1,3/4},{1/4,3/4}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}],
   Line[{{1/4,3/4},{-1/4,3/4}}],
   BSplineCurve[{{-1/4,3/4},{-1,3/4},{-1,0}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}],
   BSplineCurve[{{-1,0},{-1,-3/4},{-(1/4),-3/4}},SplineWeights->{1,1/Sqrt[2],1}],
   Line[{{-1/4,-3/4},{1/4,-3/4}}]
};
Graphics[{{Red,segments},Lighter[Purple,3/4],FilledCurve[alef[segments]]}]
```

produces

[image: filled curve bug]

as desired.

Comment: slightly shorter: `aleph = MapAt[Rest, #, {2 ;;, 1}]&`

Comment: Indeed, that works, too. Thanks.

Comment: @kglr: I have incorporated your comment into my answer (with attribution).