# Texture prevents JoinedCurve from closing

Tags: graphics, bugs, splines, filling, textures

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier and fixed in 12.1**

---

I am running Mathematica 11.3 and would like to see if this behavior is still present in newer versions of Mathematica before submitting a bug report.

---

Here is my example code

```
triangle[txtrq_] := 
 Module[{arcs = {
     BSplineCurve[{{1, 0}, {1, Sqrt[3]/3}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}},
      SplineWeights -> {1, Sqrt[3]/2, 1}], 
     BSplineCurve[{(*{1/2,Sqrt[3]/2},*){0, Sqrt[3]/3}, {0, 0}}, 
      SplineWeights -> {1, Sqrt[3]/2, 1}], 
     BSplineCurve[{(*{0,0},*){1/2, -Sqrt[3]/6}, {1, 0}}, 
      SplineWeights -> {1, Sqrt[3]/2, 1}]}, txtr}, 
  txtr = Graphics[{Thickness[1/8], RGBColor[1, 7/8, 0], 
     Line[{{{0, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}}, {{1/2, 0}, {1, 1/2}},
         {{0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0}}, {{1/2, 1}, {1, 1/2}}}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]; 
  Graphics[{Sequence @@ If[txtrq, {Texture[txtr]}, {}], 
    RGBColor[1, 7/8, 0], 
    FilledCurve[arcs, 
     Sequence @@ 
      If[txtrq, {VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
         20 {{1, 0}, {1, Sqrt[3]/3}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2},
           (*{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2},*){0, Sqrt[3]/3}, {0, 0},
           (*{0, 0},*){1/2, -Sqrt[3]/6}, {1, 0}}}, {}]], 
    RGBColor[1/5, 1/2, 1], Thickness[1/50], 
    JoinedCurve[arcs, CurveClosed -> True]}, ImageSize -> 400]]
```

Note that I have commented out the first point in all but the first of the **BSplineCurve** structures in **arcs** and the corresponding points in the **VertexTextureCoordinates**. This is explained in the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/233846).

---

Here is the output with the **Texture** and **VertexTextureCoordinates** removed:

`triangle[False]`

[image]

Here is the output with the **Texture** and **VertexTextureCoordinates** included:

`triangle[True]`

[image]

Note that the **JoinedCurve** is closed in the absence of the **Texture** in the **FilledCurve**.  However, when the **Texture** is present in the **FilledCurve**, the **JoinedCurve** fails to close (the bottom right corner lacks its mitered join). It seems odd that an option to one graphics directive causes a problem in the rendering of another.

Does this behavior persist in newer versions of Mathematica?

Comment: Can you try adding `Directive[JoinForm["Round"], CapForm["Round"]]` before all the other primitives to see what happens?

Comment: I'm on MMA 12.0.0.0 on Mac and the problem persists.

Comment: @J.M.: I bet that hides the problem, but I'll try.

Comment: @N.J.Evans: Thanks. I will start writing up a bug report.

Comment: @J.M.'sennui: I tried adding `Directive[JoinForm["Round"], CapForm["Round"]]` and also `JoinForm["Round"], CapForm["Round"]`, but neither changed the output at all. Did you expect that?

Comment: Yep, definitely a bug... let's wait for someone with 12.2 to confirm.

Comment: @J.M.'sennui: I did an image difference, and there is a small difference at the two joins of both drawings: the round join is very small, but those joins are "Round".  The caps are still "Butt".

Comment: Work fine in 12.2. The bug had been fixed.

Comment: @cvgmt: Thanks! If you would, would you please post an answer with both drawings as 12.2 renders them?

Comment: Works in version 12.1

Comment: @DanielHuber: Thanks! I already have 12.1, but I need to update my OS before it will run. This adds a reason to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bug had been fixed. Here we attach the result.

```
$Version
(* 12.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 9, 2020) *)
Row[triangle /@ {True, False}]
```

[image]