# Calligraphic Pen Signature Pane

Tags: graphics, dynamic, locator

This exchange about writing the infinity symbol using a calligraphic pen nib (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13376/43662) gave me an idea that is a bit steep for me to implement.

The idea is to create a large pane (a `DynamicModule` with a `TouchPosition`?) which on a machine with a touchscreen can be used to create a signature and export it to any graphics format for use in letters. The pane would track touching it (or clicking the mouse and moving it) and repeatedly so (i.e., raise the pen and write again). The result would be the signature but without the calligraphic pen effect.

Then, akin to the answer above, the user would assess the effect of changing the nib angle, width, and ink color. The user would save the shape for adjusting again in the future and export the calligraphic signature for importing into letters.

To Be Updated as We Work this Out: After updating according to N0va's first attempt and Michael E2's cautionary note I am trying to use `MousePosition` instead of `TouchPosition` until we get this code working but I am stuck. My goal is something akin to:

```
DynamicModule[{pt=Dynamic@MousePosition["Graphics"],tmp},(
tmp=If[pt!=None&&pt!=tmp[[-1]],AppendTo[tmp,pt],{0,0}];
Graphics[{...,Line@tmp])]
```

Accordingly, following None's example with `LocatorPanel`, I produced the following code, which does not produce a similar result:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = Dynamic@MousePosition["Graphics"], tmp = {}}, {
  Dynamic@Graphics[{
     Line@{{2.5, 2.5}, pt},
     , Line[AppendTo[tmp, pt]]}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Medium, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}], pt, tmp}]
```

The last instance of `tmp` never appears different than `{}`. However, when I move the mouse fast inside the graph, a line of a few points corresponding to a `tmp` different than `{}` does appear:

[image]

Why does `tmp` get reset?

Comment: You really ought to ask a question, this is, after all, a Question and Answer sort of place.

Comment: Probably need `Dynamic[]` in there somewhere.

Comment: @MichaelE2 `Dynamic@gr` does not do it.

Comment: Is that how `TouchPosition` is supposed to work? The docs do not put `Dynamic` on the enclosing head. (I don't think `gr` can be the head of an enclosing object. Probably it should be `Graphics`.) See how N0va used `Dynamic` to update `tmp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not familiar with `TouchPosition` but I got something to work with `LocatorPane`

```
pts={};
inputField[]:=DynamicModule[{tmp={},pt={0,0}},
  Panel[
    LocatorPane[Dynamic@pt,Dynamic@ListLinePlot[If[pt=!={0,0},AppendTo[tmp,pt],{}],PlotRange->{{0,1},{0,1}},Axes->False]],
    Row[{Button["Save",pts=tmp],Button["Reset",tmp={};pt={0,0};]}]
  ]
]
inputField[]
```

which creates a canvas to draw on
[image: Input]

which can be saved to the variable `pts` by pressing the `Save` button in the panel. The canvas gets reset (not the `pts`) when pressing the `Reset` button.

Comment: I'd probably use `DynamicModule` instead of `Module`.

Comment: I get a FrontEnd warning message "pt in Dynamic occurs where it is not going to be evaluated before going out of scope". No idea what that means. More importantly, this code only works for "writing" by using the mouse. Moving a finger moves the locator pane. Moving a finger on the mousepad produces excessive cursor movement.

Comment: Let me put my comment more forcefully for others who might wish to use or adapt this code: ["Module variables should *never* appear inside Dynamics or Manipulates internal to that Module." — John Fultz](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Sep/msg00198.html)

Comment: @MichaelE2 OK, I think that I cleaned the code accordingly, but it still does not work.

Comment: I made the change to `DynamicModule` and it works fine for me: the change eliminated some syntax warnings related to Michael E2's comments and it still works as intended for me.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. If you want to see one problem, execute the original `Module` code for `inputField[]` and then execute `Quit[]`. The `LocatorPane` will stop working because the module variables are not reinitialized. With `DynamicModule`, they are, but the FE shows a pink box from an error message about `ToBoxes`, which lasts until the kernel finishes restarting and can evaluate `ToBoxes[..]` (examine the cell expression of the output cell to see where `ToBoxes[]` occurs). That seems unnecessary and irritating to me.

Comment: @N0va Could you recast this using `DynamicModule[{pt=Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"],...]` instead of using a `LocatorModule` and `ListLinePlot`? I cannot do that.