# Calligraphic Pen Signature, Part II

Tags: graphics

Continuing toward my goal pf getting a calligraphic signature pane pursuant to this answer (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13376/43662). I have produced the code below. The user writes using the mouse with the button held down. Subsequent presses produce new lines. Color and pen shape and angle are chosen.

**Update**

I am trying to combine with `BSplineFunction` in order to smoothen the angles and make the curves flow more evenly. It is better but can be improved.

The code for the angular panel:

```
mouseHandler := Block[{},
  (pos = MousePosition["Graphics"];
   btn = CurrentValue[{"MouseButtonTest", 1}];
   If[btn, (
     If[pos =!= None, AppendTo[posList[maxLine], pos]];
     posList[maxLine] = DeleteDuplicates@posList[maxLine];),
    (*else increment line counter and max line counter*)
    If[Length@posList[maxLine] > 3,
     maxLine++]];
   If[maxLine == 100, Break];
   )]
calligraphicLine[pts_List, baseThickness_, maxThickness_, 
  direction_] := ({Thickness[(Abs@
          Sin[Mod[ArcTan @@ Subtract @@ # + direction, 2 Pi]])*
        maxThickness + baseThickness], Line[#]} & /@ 
   Partition[pts, 2, 1])
Table[posList[i] = {}, {i, 100}];
posList[1] = Table[{-10 - i, -i}, {i, 4}]; maxLine = 1;
colr = RGBColor[0., 0.5, 0.9];
thinX = .001; thickX = .015; angle = 5.48;
Column[{Row@{
    ColorSlider[Dynamic[colr]],
    Column[{"\tNib Thin Dimension\t" Slider[
        Dynamic[thinX], {0.0001, .01}],
      "\tNib Thick dimenson\t" Slider[Dynamic[thickX], {.01, .025}],
      "\tNib Angle\t\t\t" Slider[Dynamic[angle], {0, 2 Pi}]}]
    },
  Dynamic[Graphics[{colr, Dynamic@Table[
       calligraphicLine[posList[i], thinX, thickX, angle]
       , {i, maxLine}],
     Black
     ,(*Dynamic@*)Table[
      Point[posList[i]]
      , {i, maxLine}]
     }, Frame -> False, FrameTicks -> False,
    AspectRatio -> Automatic,
    ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}}]]
  }]
Dynamic[mouseHandler]
```

To get the smoother lines, I follow it with

```
Show@Table[
  ParametricPlot[BSplineFunction[posList[i], SplineDegree -> 5][t]
    , {t, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 4 60, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}}, 
    PlotStyle -> colr, Axes -> False] /. 
   Line[pts_] :> calligraphicLine[pts, thinX, thickX, angle]
  , {i, 2, maxLine - 1}]
```

For example, panel one and two might be, panel one:

[image]

and panel two:

[image]

The ends have blotches and the curves, while better, are not realistic.

Comment: Interesting.  Is the nib angle held constant throughout ?

Comment: @QuantumDot Yes, I do not know how or why one would think about changing the nib angle midstroke or between strokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proposed solution:

```
Manipulate[
 (Show[{(gr =
      Graphics[
       If[lineEx < 2, 
        White, {nibColor, 
         Table[With[{i = i}, 
           calligraphicLine[smoothedPoints[posList[i]], nibThinDim, 
            nibThickDim, nibAngle]], {i, Max[0, lineEx - 1]}]}], 
       PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> Large])
    , Graphics[{nibColor,
      Dynamic[
       Block[{
         mousePos = 
          MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, 
           deftMsPos = {-1.89, 1.32}],
         mouseBtn = CurrentValue[{"MouseButtonTest", 1}],
         line = lineEx}, {
         locatorRectangle[mousePos, nibThinDim, nibThickDim, nibAngle],
         If[mouseBtn,
          (If[mousePos =!= None && mousePos != deftMsPos, 
            AppendTo[posList[line], mousePos]];
           calligraphicLine[posList[line], nibThinDim, nibThickDim, 
            nibAngle]),
          If[Length[posList[line]] > 3, line++; lineEx++;
           If[lineEx > 100, Break[]]]]}]],
      Black, Dashing[.01], Circle[{-2, 1.5}, .3],
      Text["Pen rest", {-2, 1.5}, {-1, 1}]
      }, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> Large]
    }])
 ,
 {{nibColor, RGBColor[0., 0.6, 0.8], 
   "Ink color"}, Black, Control -> ColorSlider},
 {{nibThinDim, .01, "Nib thin dimension"}, .0001, .1},
 {{nibThickDim, .1, "Nib thick dimension"}, .05, .3},
 {{nibAngle, RandomReal[{.35, .5}], "Nib angle"}, 0, \[Pi]},
 Delimiter,
 Column[{Row[{
     Button[
      "Reset canvas", {Table[posList[i] = {}, {i, 100}]; lineEx = 1}],
     Button[
      "Delete Last Stroke", {posList[lineEx - 1] = {}; 
       lineEx = lineEx - 1}]}],
   Button["Save as Signature_Temp.jpg", 
    Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, 
       "Signature_Temp.jpg"}], Show[gr, PlotRange -> All]]],
   Button["Save as Signature_Temp.pdf", 
    Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, 
       "Signature_Temp.pdf"}], Show[gr, PlotRange -> All]]]}]
 , ControlPlacement -> Left
 , Initialization :> {
   lineEx = 1,
   calligraphicLine[pts_List, thin_, thick_, angle_] := 
    Map[calLineComp[#[[1]], #[[2]], thin, thick, angle] &, 
     Partition[pts, 2, 1]],
   calLineComp[point1_, point2_, thin_, thick_, angle_] := Block[{
      p1lr = 
       point1 + {Cos[angle] (thick/2) + Sin[angle] (thin/2), 
         Sin[angle] (thick/2) - 
          Cos[angle] (thin/2)},(*lower right of point1*)
      p1ur = 
       point1 + {Cos[angle] (thick/2) - Sin[angle] (thin/2), 
         Sin[angle] (thick/2) + Cos[angle] (thin/2)},(*upper right*)
      p1ul = 
       point1 - {Cos[angle] (thick/2) + Sin[angle] (thin/2), 
         Sin[angle] (thick/2) - Cos[angle] (thin/2)},
      p1ll = 
       point1 - {Cos[angle] (thick/2) - Sin[angle] (thin/2), 
         Sin[angle] (thick/2) + Cos[angle] (thin/2)},
      p2lr = 
       point2 + {Cos[angle] (thick/2) + Sin[angle] (thin/2), 
         Sin[angle] (thick/2) - Cos[angle] (thin/2)},
      p2ur = 
       point2 + {Cos[angle] (thick/2) - Sin[angle] (thin/2), 
         Sin[angle] (thick/2) + Cos[angle] (thin/2)},
      p2ul = 
       point2 - {Cos[angle] (thick/2) + Sin[angle] (thin/2), 
         Sin[angle] (thick/2) - Cos[angle] (thin/2)},
      p2ll = 
       point2 - {Cos[angle] (thick/2) - Sin[angle] (thin/2), 
         Sin[angle] (thick/2) + Cos[angle] (thin/2)}},
     {
      Polygon[{p1lr, p1ur, p1ul, p1ll}],(*starting poly*)
      Polygon[{p2lr, p2ur, p2ul, p2ll}],(*ending poly*)
      Polygon[{p1lr, p2lr, p2ur, p1ur}],(*polys connecting each side*)
      Polygon[{p1ur, p2ur, p2ul, p1ul}], 
      Polygon[{p1ul, p2ul, p2ll, p1ll}], 
      Polygon[{p1ll, p2ll, p2lr, p1lr}]}],
   locatorRectangle[point_, thin_, thick_, angle_] := 
    Polygon[{point + {Cos[angle] (thick/2) + Sin[angle] (thin/2), 
        Sin[angle] (thick/2) - Cos[angle] (thin/2)},
      point + {Cos[angle] (thick/2) - Sin[angle] (thin/2), 
        Sin[angle] (thick/2) + Cos[angle] (thin/2)},
      point - {Cos[angle] (thick/2) + Sin[angle] (thin/2), 
        Sin[angle] (thick/2) - Cos[angle] (thin/2)},
      point - {Cos[angle] (thick/2) - Sin[angle] (thin/2), 
        Sin[angle] (thick/2) + Cos[angle] (thin/2)}}],
   smoothedPoints[pts_List] := 
    smoothedPoints[pts] = 
     Table[BSplineFunction[pts][t], {t, 0, 1, 0.005}],
   Table[posList[i] = {}, {i, 100}]
   }]
```

An example:

[image]